# Collapsible menu has all drop down menu's expanded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a website for a project and i'm not allowed to use frameworks (so no bootstrap), i've now run into a problem where the navigation bar when collapsed (screen width under 800px) has all the individual links expanded, rather than being in individual categories.

I've uploaded this website to 
[here](http://www.ico.mmu.ac.uk/13143651/webdev/index.html)

```
The Html nav bar

<nav role="navigation" id="cssmenu">
<ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>

    <li class="has-sub"><a href="pages/courses.html">Courses</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="pages/courses/media.html">Digital Media</a></li>
            <li><a href="pages/courses/webdev.html">Web Development</a></li>
            <li><a href="pages/courses/journalism.html">Journalism</a></li>
            <li class="last"><a href="pages/courses/infocomms.html">Information & Communications</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="has-sub"><a href="pages/facilities.html">Facilities</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="pages/facilities/society.html">Societies</a></li>
            <li><a href="pages/facilities/jobs.html">Jobs and Placements</a></li>
            <li class="last"><a href="pages/facilities/library.html">Library</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="has-sub"><a href="pages/manchester.html">Manchester & Student Life</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="pages/manchester/travel.html">Travel</a></li>
            <li><a href="pages/manchester/attractions.html">Attractions</a></li>
            <li class="last"><a href="pages/manchester/night.html">Nightlife</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="has-sub"><a href="pages/help.html">Student Help</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="pages/help/finance.html">Finance</a></li>
            <li><a href="pages/help/union.html">Student Union</a></li>
            <li class="last"><a href="pages/help/assist.html">Assistance</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="last"><a href="pages/contact.html">Contact</a></li>

    </ul>
</nav>
```

The Jquery script

```
( function( $ ) {
$( document ).ready(function() {
// Cache the elements we'll need
var menu = $('#cssmenu');
var menuList = menu.find('ul:first');
var listItems = menu.find('li').not('#responsive-tab');

// Create responsive trigger
menuList.prepend('<li id="responsive-tab"><a href="#">Digi-Co</a></li>');

// Toggle menu visibility
menu.on('click', '#responsive-tab', function(){
    listItems.slideToggle('fast');
    listItems.addClass('collapsed');
});
});
} )( jQuery );
```

The css can also be found 
[here](http://www.ico.mmu.ac.uk/13143651/webdev/cssmenu/styles.css)

Any help will be appreciated, i'm sure its just a simple overwriting syntax, but i can't be too sure, whether it's that or if it's a scripting problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried this out in different browsers? It seems to work fine for me on Chrome.

Comment: you state you can't use any frameworks (so no bootstrap) but are using jquery?  whaaattttt?

Comment: When you say it works on your chrome, you resized the window to under 800px, clicked on the dropdown collapsible menu and all the links were in subcategories, unexpanded? (as in courses, facilities, manchester / student help all broke down into an individual dropdown menus, rather than all the links being shown in a row?

I believe that Jquery was excluded from the frameworks for this project. Sorry for the confusion.